# Is there a way to write up a custom loss function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to write up a custom MSE loss function in keras?

My training sample is cross-sectional data of k x n inputs and my outputs are a k x 1 at time t, but t ranges from t-1 to t-120 (monthly time stamps of cross-sectional data).

I want to write up a custom MSE loss function that essentially puts a lower weight on training samples t-120 and a higher weight on training samples t-1.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is some simple code to write up a custom loss function in keras.

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):

    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)  # Note the `axis=-1`

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss_fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class weights in order to specify a custom weight for each of your output units and then specify it on model.fit() [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#train_a_model_with_class_weights)

Comment: Thanks for this Angel. I looked it up - instead of class weights (which would work on classification problems) one can actually specify sample weights in model.fit() and that seems to do the trick. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :D